# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.jobyab.controllers.registerController.doPost

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

It looks something is going wrong with `persist` method of `EntityManager` class. I use apache tomcat and recieve `HTTP Status 500-` page every time I try.

This is `DataQuery` class:

```
public class DataQuery {
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em;

    public DataQuery() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.sbu.ac.jobyab");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public void registerUser(Employee e){
        em.persist(e);
    }
}
```

And this is the registerController class that recieves input from user and do the registeration task:

```
public class registerController extends HttpServlet {
    private DataQuery query;
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = request.getParameter("register_email");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("register_password");
        Employee e = new Employee(10, email, pwd);
        query.registerUser(e);
    }
}
```

This is full stack error :

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.jobyab.controllers.registerController.doPost(registerController.java:39)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.33 logs.

Comment: can you paste full error stack?

Comment: tnx for the comment. i add the error in update :) @ypp

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from Apache Tomcat/8.0.33 logs ?

Comment: You basically asked "Why do I get a NullPointerException?". The duplicate answers that. Once you're capable of asking "Why is variable X null?" while pointing out the exact variable X in a MCVE code snippet, and you still can't figure out the solution, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with adding `query = new DataQuery();` inside doPost() method

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is null

```
private DataQuery query;
```

It should probably be injected using `@Inject` or `@EJB`

```
@EJB
private DataQuery query;
```

But could be something else, whats on line 39 of your controller ?

Comment: On line 39, I have `query.registerUser(e);`
after adding @EJB annotation it doesn't change something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you Tomcat comes with an EJB container or CDI Container, so the possibility of injecting it with an `@EJB` or `@Inject` notation is off. You might have to programmatically create a `DataQuery` instance and use it, as explained by @ypp.